# Can I store Latex/.tex in a database which when read and displayed will be shown as equations and diagrams?

Tags: database

How can I store latex in a database whilst ensuring when displayed, it shows correctly(displays equations etc)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Store the source code and compile when reading...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I go about compiling the .tex file from within a database?

Comment: @JerrySpranger Can you please explain your question further?

Comment: Yes, I essentially have LaTeX which I want to store inside a DB, which I plan on reading and displaying. However I do not want it to display the LaTeX code. I want it to display my equations and diagrams etc. I am trying to figure out how I can do this. A pdf would be preffered

Comment: You cannot compile within the database. When reading you save it in RAM or on a fast hard drive (e.g. `/tmp/` or something like this), run a pdflatex compilation on it and then use the output...

Comment: Simples IF you can run shell commands from the database with snippets so blob =core.tex copy header+core+trailer.tex to run.tex > pdfLaTeX run.tex > pdfviewer run.pdf this all presumes you have a minimal latex with pdfLaTeX on path